# Hibernate é considerado white box ou black box?

Tags: java, hibernate

Pelo que entendo os frameworks, *Black box* são conhecidos pela sua facilidade na utilização visto que não é necessário entender o que ocorre por dentro dele para utilizar, e o *white box* o contrário, é necessário um conhecimento da estrutura interna do framework para utilização.

No caso do Hibernate, em qual categoria ele se encontra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bem, duvido que algum framework puramente *black box* exista por dois motivos simples. O primeiro é devido a [**lei das *leaky abstractions***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) e o segundo é que para se usar o framework, é necessário saber ao menos alguma coisa mínima das classes ou métodos que nele existem para que você tenha alguma API pública. Assim sendo, algo completamente *black box* simplesmente não é utilizável.

Mas a questão é o quão profundamente esta API pública (ou mesmo não-pública) se embrenha e o quanto o programador deve se aventurar nela para que o framework possa ser utilizado. Se a API pública de um framework for relativamente simples, coesa, intuitiva, fornecer um baixo acoplamento e não demandar conhecimentos profundos sobre detalhes de funcionamento do framework, então ela é provavelmente o mais *black* que poderia ser. Pode até ser que haja detalhes mais profundos da API pública para os hackers de plantão poderem fazer tunagens ou customizações internas por qualquer motivo que seja, mas podemos desconsiderar o caso de APIs públicas internas para casos específicos. O problema é quando o acesso a detalhes internos ou a nuances do funcionamento do framework torna-se essencial para seu uso.

De qualquer modo, eu o considero o *Hibernate* relativamente *black box*, uma vez que é bem possível programar usando o *Hibernate* por meio apenas interfaces do JPA (ex: `EntityManager`) e anotações. Obviamente, que você tem que saber usar a API pública do JPA e conhecer o significado das anotações, e por vezes elas podem ser um tanto complicadinhas. Além disso, de vez em quando algum detalhe sórdido de relações `@ManyToMany`, caches, limitações de *fetching* de múltiplas entidades relacionadas a um único registro, ou propriedades específicas que você vai precisar no `persistence.xml` aparecem como *leaky abstractions* ou como detalhes *white box*, e por vezes algum detalhe interno do *Hibernate* faz-se necessário ser usado ou ao menos compreendido. Por isso, eu o classificaria como majoritariamente *black box*, algo como um *dark gray box*.

Um contra-exemplo seria o caso do *Swing*. Existe um montão de métodos para fazer todo tipo de coisa, muitas vezes de forma não-intuitiva, redundante ou com interações bem complexas entre si. Isso resulta em classes super-pesadas que acumulam vários níveis de herança coletando centenas de métodos no caminho. Além disso, há vários detalhes complexos sobre *Event Dispatch Thread*, gerenciamento de desenho de componentes usando Java2D, diferenças entre componentes heavyweight e lightweight, complexas formas de obter e passar o foco entre elementos, e mais um monte de coisas que fazem com que usar esta API seja uma coisa difícil para poder trabalhar com ele de forma eficiente (e provavelmente um dos principais motivos pelo qual ele nunca decolou de fato, ficando atrás de seus concorrentes e reduzido a determinados nichos). Logo, o *Swing* é majoritariamente *white box* (algo como um *pale gray box*).

Answer (score 3):

White box. Afinal você tem acesso aos fontes caso queira testar de modo totalmente transparente. Black box por exemplo são componentes dos quais você não tem como acessar ou modificar seu comportamento.

Se sua pergunta foi relacionada com a Teoria Geral de Sistemas ou Testes, essa é a resposta correta.